# Error producing to embedded kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to embed a kafkaserver in my code. I've used the following example code to try to learn how to do so but for some reason, my producer can't send messages to the embedded server (it times out after 60 secs). I'm using kafka 0.8.2.2. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import kafka.api.FetchRequest;
import kafka.api.FetchRequestBuilder;
import kafka.javaapi.FetchResponse;
import kafka.javaapi.TopicMetadata; 
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer;
import kafka.javaapi.message.ByteBufferMessageSet;
import kafka.message.MessageAndOffset;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;
import kafka.server.KafkaConfig;
import kafka.server.KafkaServer;
import kafka.utils.Time;
import kafka.utils.Utils;
import org.apache.commons.collections.functors.ExceptionPredicate;
import org.apache.curator.test.TestingServer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaLocalBroker {

public static final String TEST_TOPIC = "test-topic";

public KafkaConfig kafkaConfig;
public KafkaServer kafkaServer;
public TestingServer zookeeper;


public KafkaLocalBroker() throws Exception{

        zookeeper = new TestingServer(true);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper.getConnectString());
        props.put("broker.id", 0);
        kafkaConfig = new KafkaConfig(props);

        kafkaServer = new KafkaServer(kafkaConfig, new Time() {
            public long nanoseconds() {
                return System.nanoTime();
            }

            public long milliseconds() {
                return System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

            public void sleep(long ms) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(ms);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    // Do Nothing
                }
            }
        });
        kafkaServer.startup();
        System.out.println("embedded kafka is up");
    }

    public void stop(){
        kafkaServer.shutdown();
        System.out.println("embedded kafka stop");
    }

    /**
     * a main that tests the embedded kafka
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    KafkaLocalBroker kafkaLocalBroker = null;
        //init kafka server and start it:
        try {
            kafkaLocalBroker = new KafkaLocalBroker();
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 1);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

        //send one message to local kafka server:
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(TEST_TOPIC, "test-message" + i);
            producer.send(data, (metadata, exception) -> {
                if (exception != null) {

                    System.out.println("Failed to write log message: " + exception.getMessage());

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Successful write to offset {} in partition {} on topic {}: " +
                            metadata.offset() + ", " + metadata.partition() + ", "+ metadata.topic());

                }
            });
        }

        //consume messages from Kafka:
        SimpleConsumer consumer = new SimpleConsumer("localhost", 9092, 10000, 1024000, "clientId");
        long offset = 0L;
        while (offset < 160) { //this is an exit criteria just for this test so we are not stuck in enless loop
            // create a fetch request for topic “test”, partition 0, current offset, and fetch size of 1MB
            FetchRequest fetchRequest = new FetchRequestBuilder().addFetch(TEST_TOPIC, 0, offset, 100000).build();//new FetchRequest(TEST_TOPIC, 0, offset, 1000000);

            // get the message set from the consumer and print them out
            FetchResponse messages = consumer.fetch(fetchRequest);
            for(MessageAndOffset msg : messages.messageSet(TEST_TOPIC, 0)) {

                ByteBuffer payload = msg.message().payload();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[payload.limit()];
                payload.get(bytes);
                try {
                    System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
                } catch (Exception e){

                }
                // advance the offset after consuming each message
                offset = msg.offset();
            }
        }

        producer.close();
        //close the consumer
        consumer.close();
        //stop the kafka broker:
        if(kafkaLocalBroker != null) {
            kafkaLocalBroker.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've included the exception returned from the producer below:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.

Comment: How do you caracterize the failure ? Any specific error message ? Are you sure it's the producer, not the consumer, having a problem ?

Comment: The producer.send hangs for 60 seconds and then spits out the TimeoutException I've included in the edit above.

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: I upgraded my version to 0.10.0.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The properties used to create kafka producer is not valid for 0.8. Go through [producerconfig](http://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#producerconfigs) and change the properties. or update kafka version

Comment: Do I use 'org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer' or 'org.apache.kafka.producer.Producer'?

Comment: I get this exception when I use the configs given in the included link: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers" which has no default value.

Comment: It seems like the kafka producer needs at least bootstrap.servers, key.serializer, and value.serializer for the config